# How to avoid penalty of pickling a dict vs pickling a list

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

**Introduction**

I have a dictionary with the following format:

```
dict_list = {'S0':[[list of int],[list of int]], 'S1':[[list of int],[list of int]], ...}
```

with S0's list of ints accessed via

```
dict_list['S0'][0] and dict_list['S0'][1]
```

To improve code readability, I changed the "list of list" to "dict of list" as follows:

```
dict_dict = {'S0': {'list0': [list of int], 'list1': [list of int]}, ...}
```

which results in more readable code when accessing the lists:

```
dict_dict['S0']['list0'] and dict_dict['S0']['list1']
```

**Pickle Problem**

However, when I pickled and saved the dict_dict to file, it turns out the penalty of having additional dict keys actually scales in proportion to the number of 'S#' entries. It seems that pickle isn't storing the dict "smartly" as it stores each and every dict key separately.

Now, we realize that this is, after all, how pickle should work, since each 'S#' could have had different sets of keys to begin with. There is no way for pickle to know beforehand that our dict_dict is actually just a table with regularly repeating fields.

**The Question**

My question is, is there an alternative to `dict_list` wherein the list of ints can be accessed by a string key (as in `dict_dict`) but without the pickle penalty described above?

***UPDATE: Experiments Based on Comments Given***

```
3,100 bytes - dict_list['S0'][0] (list.bin)
3,314 bytes - dict_dict['S0']['list0'] (dict.bin)
3,922 bytes - dict_class['S0'].list0 (class.bin)
5,855 bytes - dict_namedtuple['S0'].list0 (namedtuple.bin)
```

---

```
s_list = ['S0','S1','S2','S3','S4','S5','S6','S7','S8','S9','S10','S11','S12','S13','S14','S15','S0a','S1a','S2a','S3a','S4a','S5a','S6a','S7a','S8a','S9a','S10a','S11a','S12a','S13a','S14a','S15a','AA0','AA1','AA2','AA3','AA4','AA5','AA6','AA7','AA8','AA9','AA10','AA11','AA12','AA13','AA14','AA15','AA0a','AA1a','AA2a','AA3a','AA4a','AA5a','AA6a','AA7a','AA8a','AA9a','AA10a','AA11a','AA12a','AA13a','AA14a','AA15a','BB0','BB1','BB2','BB3','BB4','BB5','BB6','BB7','BB8','BB9','BB10','BB11','BB12','BB13','BB14','BB15','BB0a','BB1a','BB2a','BB3a','BB4a','BB5a','BB6a','BB7a','BB8a','BB9a','BB10a','BB11a','BB12a','BB13a','BB14a','BB15a']
num_of_s_entries = 32
list_length = 5

def pickle_n_save(dict_var, filename):
    outfile = open(filename, "wb")
    pickle.dump(dict_var, outfile)
    outfile.close()

# ------------------------------------------------------------dict_list['S0'][0]
dict_list = {}
for s in s_list[0:num_of_s_entries]:
    dict_list[s] = [[],[]]
    for pts in range(0,list_length):
        dict_list[s][0].append(randrange(1,100))
        dict_list[s][1].append(randrange(1,100)*1000)

pickle_n_save(dict_list, "list.bin")

# -----------------------------------------------------dict_dict['S0']['list0']
dict_dict = {}
for s in dict_list.keys():
    dict_dict[s] = {}
    dict_dict[s]['list0'] = dict_list[s][0]
    dict_dict[s]['list1'] = dict_list[s][1]

pickle_n_save(dict_dict, "dict.bin")

# -------------------------------------------------------dict_class['S0'].list0
class S:
    def __init__(self, list0, list1):
        self.list0 = list0
        self.list1 = list1

dict_class = {}
for s in dict_list.keys():
    dict_class[s] = S(dict_list[s][0],dict_list[s][1])

pickle_n_save(dict_class, "class.bin")

# ---------------------------------------------------dict_namedtuple['S0'].list0
S_namedtuple = namedtuple('S_namedtuple', ['list0','list1'])
dict_namedtuple = {}
for s in dict_list.keys():
    dict_namedtuple[s] = S_namedtuple(dict_list[s][0],dict_list[s][1])

pickle_n_save(dict_namedtuple, "namedtuple.bin")
```

Comment: I don't really see how using `'list1'` as a key is more readable or better than just using `1` as a list index.

Comment: I don't know, but I prefer to use 'dates' and 'person' as keys rather than having to remember that 0 is for 'dates' and 1 is for 'person'.

Comment: Why not use a class having 'dates' and 'person' as attributes? Does that also add a penalty?

Comment: @silvernightstar: Well, that is quite different.  But if you are using `dates` and `person`, then there is no "smart" way to store them numerically, since the keys aren't numerical at all.

Comment: What about wrapping the `list` as your own defined `dict`, say `mydict`, and in `mydict`, you access the the elements using a string, which will then be converted into a number ('list0' to 0) in the `__getitem__` method?

Comment: @Anubhav I tried using class with 'list0' and 'list1' attributes whose code is shown above. Is this what you mean? If so, it seems to be worse than using a dict.

Comment: @silvernightstar Yes. Seeing as nothing people can think of seems to be smaller than the list, I'd suggest pickling your data as lists and converting it to dicts (or classes, or whatever) when unpickling it.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want a [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using namedtuple (code shown in UPDATED section of original question). Do you see any problems with my implementation?